# Relative Frequency Histograms and Probability Density Functions

Tags: matlab, histogram, probability, dice

The function called DicePlot simulates rolling 10 dice 5000 times.

The function calculates the sum of values of the 10 dice of each roll, which will be a 1 ⇥ 5000 vector, and plot relative frequency histogram with edges of bins being selected in where each bin in the histogram represents a possible value of for the sum of the dice.

The mean and standard deviation of the 1 ⇥ 5000 sums of dice values will be computed, and the probability density function of normal distribution (with the mean and standard deviation computed) on top of the relative frequency histogram will be plotted.

Below is my code so far -  What am I doing wrong? The graph shows up but not the extra red line on top? I looked at answers like this, and I don't think I'll be plotting anything like the Gaussian function.

```
% function[]= DicePlot()
for roll=1:5000
    diceValues = randi(6,[1, 10]);
    SumDice(roll) = sum(diceValues);
end
distr=zeros(1,6*10);
for i = 10:60
    distr(i)=histc(SumDice,i);
end
bar(distr,1)
Y = normpdf(X)
xlabel('sum of dice values')
ylabel('relative frequency')
title(['NumDice = ',num2str(NumDice),' , NumRolls = ',num2str(NumRolls)]); 
  end
```

It is supposed to look like 
[image]

But it looks like

[image]

Comment: Can you please clarify your problem?

Comment: Yeah, what's your issue, the code seems to run fine for me other than your variable NumDice used on the last line is never defined.

Comment: my graph looks like: http://i1308.photobucket.com/albums/s617/pingchu93/ScreenShot2012-11-21at102036AM_zpsc26c358d.jpg it is supposed to look like http://i1308.photobucket.com/albums/s617/pingchu93/YEAHBUDDY_zps6690a18a.jpg

Comment: sorry i don't understand what "they run more stimulations" mean. can you clarify? i'm following the problem exactly i just don't know what i'm doing wrong :(

Comment: The problem is that you aren't telling us why you are unhappy with your plot. The only real difference I see between the two plots you linked is that your plot is missing this overplotted red line. But I have no idea why you would expect that line to be there, since you don't have any code to plot such a line. Why are people upvoting this question?

Comment: Anyway, you can replace your initial for loop with `SumDice = (sum(randi(6,[10 5000]),1)`. And you can replace your second for loop with `distr=histc(SumDice,1:60)`; Matlab's vectorized operations often make code shorter and easier to understand.

Comment: Run more simulations means roll your dice more times, e.g 10k instead of 5k. The more samples you have, the smoother your histogram will look.

Comment: but why don't I have that extra red line? I used normpdf!

Comment: @PriyaSharma Okay, so that's your issue and now we can help you. Should have been specific about that in your post.

Comment: I'd suggest that you edit your original post with that information so that people dont have read through all these comments to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

The red line is not there because you aren't plotting it. Look at the documentation for `normpdf`. It computes the pdf, it doesn't plot it. So you problem is how do you add this line to the plot. The answer to that problem is to google "matlab hold on".

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code to get you going in the right direction:

```
% Normalize your distribution 
normalizedDist = distr/sum(distr);
bar(normalizedDist ,1); 
hold on

% Setup your density function using the mean and std of your sample data
mu   = mean(SumDice);
stdv = std(SumDice);
yy   = normpdf(xx,mu,stdv);
xx   = linspace(0,60);

% Plot pdf
h = plot(xx,yy,'r'); set(h,'linewidth',1.5);
```